# Web service longo periodo de execucao

Tags: java, json, web-service, restful

Estou criando um webservice que faz consultar em um DW essas consultas por terem funçoes de agregações e tudo mais levam um pouco mais de tempo que o normal (algo em torno de 2 - 5 minutos), porem o client nao espera essa consulta terminar ele entende como timeout a resposta devido ao tempo. gostaria de saber se tem como eu informar ao cliente que a consulta irá demorar e como fazer isso, abaixo as tecnologias que estou usando.

javax, webservice restful,

meu codigo é algo similar a isso:

```
@GET
@Path("/QtdeVendasNoPeriodo/{dtInicio}/{dtFim}")
@Produces("application/json; charset=UTF-8;")
public ArrayList<DetalhesVenda> QtdeVendasNoPeriodo(@PathParam("dtInicio") Date dtInicio,@PathParam("dtFim") Date dtFim){

// Logica do metodo
}
```

ate memso testar o webservice esta impossivel pois demora e as applicaçoes que conheco para testar tambem entendem como timeout o temp de resposta.

Comment: O que significa DW?

Comment: `porem o client nao espera ` o que é esse client ? é uma tela ? outra aplicação ? o mais importante é vc falar que client é esse kkk

Comment: é uma aplicacação, uma aplicaçao que ira receber desse webservice um json mais ou menos nesse formato
{
   janeiro: 10,
   fevereiro: 1000,
   marco: 6000000,
   .
   .
   dezembro: 525

}

Comment: DW significa Data warehouse

Comment: Parece q sua pergunta está duplicada aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/214371/webmetodo-timeout-exception?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Para o cliente saber quanto tempo vai demorar, você precisa enviar uma resposta. Esse tipo de problema pode ser adequadamente tratado utilizando-se uma abordagem assíncrona. Existem vantagens em se fazer isso. Por exemplo, em caso de alta demanda, vc pode enfileirar as requisições ao seu DW e não deixar threads "travadas" no seu servidor. Além disso, os clientes não precisam alterar os timeouts de conexão ao seu serviço REST. Certamente a complexidade de implementação aumenta um pouco, mas vale a pena você ter uma solução mais elegante e escalável.

Minha sugestão é que vc crie um serviço `POST /QtdeVendasNoPeriodo/{dtInicio}/{dtFim}`. Ao receber a requisição, vc submete a geração do relatório a uma thread worker e imediatamente responde ao cliente com código HTTP `202 Accepted` e o cabeçalho HTTP `Location` com o endereço onde será consultado o status da geração do relatório.
A resposta ao serviço `POST` seria algo do tipo:

```
HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted
Location: https://<seu_endereco_web>/filaProcessamento/sdf4524wrwerwe
```

`sdf4524wrwerwe` é um identificador qualquer que informa, de modo único, o status da geração do relatório. `/filaProcessamento/{idStatusProcessamento}` é um serviço `GET` onde você responderia, por exemplo:

```xml
http GET https://<seu_endereco_web>/filaProcessamento/sdf4524wrwerwe
HTTP/1.1 200 Ok

<resposta>
    <status>PENDENTE</status>
    <tempoRestante>120 segundos</tempoRestante>
    <link rel="cancel" method="delete" href="/filaProcessamento/sdf4524wrwerwe" />
</resposta>
```

Usei XML acima, mas pode ser JSON. A tag `link` seria para informar ao usuário a possibilidade de cancelar a geração do relatório. Neste caso, um serviço `DELETE` seria necessário.

Uma vez que o relatório tenha sido criado, a resposta ao serviço GET descrito acima seria

```
http GET https://<seu_endereco_web>/filaProcessamento/sdf4524wrwerwe
HTTP/1.1 303 See Other
Location: https://<seu_endereco_web>/QtdeVendasNoPeriodo/97525252665
```

O código HTTP `303` é para redirecionamento do cliente. O cabeçalho `Location` diz ao cliente onde está disponível o recurso. É necessário que você implemente um serviço `GET /QtdeVendasNoPeriodo/{idResultado}`, onde `idResultado` é um identificador qualquer do relatório esperado pelo cliente, que também será controlado por sua aplicação.

Alguns detalhes de implementação precisam ser decididos de acordo com sua necessidade. Por exemplo, como resposta ao serviço `GET /QtdeVendasNoPeriodo/{idResultado}`, informe no cabeçalho `Expires` o tempo que o relatório pode ser mantido em cache. Informe códigos HTTP consistentes, como o `404 Not Found`, caso o relatório não exista ou o `410 Gone` após o cliente já ter baixado o relatório ou sua aplicação tiver descartado os dados após um certo periodo de tempo. Enfim, diversas melhorias podem ser pensadas.

Dica de segurança: o `idResultado` pode ser, por exemplo, um número aleatório grande ou um hash. Assim, um cliente qualquer tem probabilidade baixa de conseguir acessar os resultados de outros clientes através de consultas ao serviço `GET /QtdeVendasNoPeriodo/{idResultado}`. Se você utilizar um sequencial, por exemplo, um cliente pode ter acesso a outros resultados apenas incrementando valores de `idResultado`.

Comment: cara mto obrigado pela ajuda já me da uma direçao para olhar, sei que posso estar sendo um pouco mais insistente do que deveria, mas existe algum tutorial que mostre como fazer isso ? por exemplo como eu informo o cliente com esses codigo 202 e falo para ele o local onde ele deve ir buscar o resultado? pelo que entendi teria que criar mais uns 3 ou 4 metodos para tratar essa situação.